# Get make to recompile only unchanged source files

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get my Makefile to compile only changed source files. In the Makefile below, I would like the targets: `%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.c` and `%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.s` to **only** compile if the source file has changed, or the corresponding .o object file does not exist.

Not entirely sure what's wrong here, can someone please offer some advice?

```
# Project name
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PROJECT_NAME = stm32f4_template

# Source configuration
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OUT_DIR = ./Build
SOURCE_DIR = ./Src

SOURCES  = main.c
SOURCES += startup.s

C_SOURCES  = $(filter %.c, $(SOURCES))
ASM_SOURCES +=  $(filter %.s, $(SOURCES))

OBJECTS  = $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS += $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)

# Tools 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld -v
CP = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OD = arm-none-eabi-objdump

# Compilation, linker and other tool flags
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CFLAGS  =  -I./ -c -fno-common -O0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
LFLAGS  = -nostartfiles -TLinker/memory.ld -TLinker/sections.ld
CPFLAGS = -Obinary
ODFLAGS = -S

# Target: all ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
all: setup $(PROJECT_NAME).elf
    @echo "Done! $?"

# Target: setup -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
setup:
    @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)

# Target: $(PROJECT_NAME).elf 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(PROJECT_NAME).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking $@"
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o ${OUT_DIR}/main.elf $(OUT_DIR)/main.o
    @echo

# Target %.o (.c sources)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.c # --> Execute only if source changed!!!
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
    @echo

# Target %.o (.s sources)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.s # --> Execute only if source changed!!!
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
    @echo

# Target: clean
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning build output..."
    @rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule:

```
%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.c # --> Execute only if source changed!!!
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
```

The problem is that the target of this rule is `main.o`, so Make uses it in an attempt to build `main.o`, because another target *demands* `main.o`, but what this rule actually builds is `Build/main.o`. Make keeps running this rule because it sees that `main.o` isn't there (and the rule for the elf file uses `Build/main.o`, which Make keeps rebuilding unawares).

I suggest you change it:

```
OBJECTS  = $(patsubst %.c, $(OUT_DIR)/%.o, $(C_SOURCES))

$(OUT_DIR)/%.o : ${SOURCE_DIR}/%.c # --> this should work
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The same goes for the other %.o rule.

Comment: Thanks @Beta, that seems to be almost there, but make output is as follows: `No rule to make target 'Build/main.o', needed by 'stm32f4_template.elf'`.

Comment: Scrap that, working 100% now, I had a small typo. Thanks for answering!